# How to Assign Local Variable to Local Variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table numbers:

```
number  frequency
1        6
2        2
3        8
4        5
```

In MySQL, we can dynamically assign variable without declare

```
select 
Number, 
@prev := @count as prevNumber, 
(@count := @count + Frequency) as countNumber
from Numbers
```

In SQL Server, can we do the same?

I have to declare and then use?

```
declare @prev int
declare @counts int
set @prev=0
set @counts=0

select number,
(@prev=@counts) as prevNumber,
(@counts=@counts+frquency) as countNumber from numbers
```

Obviously above code is incorrect? What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You have provided sample data, but what kind of result do you expect to end up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support user-defined variables as such.  With that said, you can achieve the same result of creating a running sum using a `window function`:

```
select number, sum(frequency) over (order by number)
from yourtable
```

- [Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/CKI56192)

---

Per the comment below, if you need the previous running sum as well, you can use a subquery with `lag` and `coalesce`:

```
select number, sum(prevnum) over (order by number) as prevNumber, countNumber
from (select *, coalesce(lag(frequency) over (order by number),0) as prevnum, 
                sum(frequency) over (order by number) as countNumber 
      from yourtable) t
```

This basically just creates multiple running sums, one for the previous amount as well.

- [Another Demo](http://rextester.com/YGBY82948)

Comment: It seems like OP also wants one with rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding (prevnumber).

Comment: @ZLK - Hmm, I figured that was just to get the running sum.  If however the OP needs that value, here's an alternative option using `lag`: http://rextester.com/YGBY82948

Comment: `SQL Server doesn't support user-defined variables as such` - that's a bold claim, unless your definition of "variable" is somehow different from the rest.

Comment: @RogerWolf -- I didn't intend to mean sql server doesn't support variables, just not when using directly in sql statements for calculations like mysql allows.  Of course `sql server` supports variables in stored procedures for example, but that's not what I understood the OP was looking for.  My understanding was the OP was asking how to create a running sum in sql server.

Comment: @sgeddes, OP has definitely added some confusion asking 2 different questions rather than 1. Still, I would recommend you to reword the quoted sentence, since it might generate A LOT of controversy in the way it is currently given.

Answer (score 0):

The specific statement that sgeddes wants to say is that a `SELECT` statement in SQL Server can assign values to a variable *or* return results, but cannot do both.  The MySQL code is doing both.

In SQL Server, you would do this using window functions.  If you want the running sum up to but not including the current value, just subtract out the current value:

```
select number,
       sum(frequency) over (order by number) as running_sum,
       (sum(frequency) over (order by number) - frequency) as running_prev_sum
from yourtable;
```

You can also use a window clause:

```
sum(frequency) over (order by number rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
```

But I find that cumbersome and less clear than just subtracting the current value.

I need to also add that your MySQL is not guaranteed to work.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  If you want to fix that, ask another question.